# errors on deleteSale method

Tags: javafx

I have that application, like a formular, I want the method deleteSale to delete a sale depending by the fisrt  name you typed, but when I try this, it gives me errors

class Controller:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> speedChoiceBox;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> dataTrafficChoiceBox;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> contractDurationChoiceBox;
    @FXML
    private TextField firstNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextArea addressArea;
    @FXML
    private TextField uniqueIdToDeleteField;
    @FXML
    private TextArea salesHistoryArea;
    @FXML
    private TextField userNameField;

    private InternetPackageModel internetPackageModel;

    public Controller() {
        this.internetPackageModel = new InternetPackageModel();
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        speedChoiceBox.getItems().addAll();
        dataTrafficChoiceBox.getItems().addAll();
        contractDurationChoiceBox.getItems().addAll();
        internetPackageModel = new InternetPackageModel();
        loadSalesHistory();
    }

    @FXML
    private void registerSale() {
        Integer speed = speedChoiceBox.getValue();
        Integer dataTraffic = dataTrafficChoiceBox.getValue();
        Integer contractDuration = contractDurationChoiceBox.getValue();
        String firstName = firstNameField.getText();
        String lastName = lastNameField.getText();
        String address = addressArea.getText();
        InternetPackage internetPackage = new InternetPackage(speed, dataTraffic, contractDuration, firstName, lastName, address);
        internetPackageModel.addSale(internetPackage);
        updateSalesHistory();
    }

    @FXML
    void deleteSale(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            String userNameToDelete = userNameField.getText();
            if (!userNameToDelete.isEmpty()) {
                internetPackageModel.deleteSale(userNameToDelete);
                updateSalesHistory();
                System.out.println("Vânzare ștearsă cu succes!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Introduceți un nume de utilizator pentru ștergere!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("A apărut o eroare la ștergerea vânzării: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }





    private void loadSalesHistory() {
        salesHistoryArea.setText(internetPackageModel.getAllSalesHistory());
    }

    private void updateSalesHistory() {
        loadSalesHistory();
    }
}
```

class InternetPackage:

```
package sample;

public class InternetPackage {
    private int speed;
    private int dataTraffic;
    private int contractDuration;
    private String uniqueId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public InternetPackage(int speed, int dataTraffic, int contractDuration, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.dataTraffic = dataTraffic;
        this.contractDuration = contractDuration;
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getDataTraffic() {
        return dataTraffic;
    }

    public void setDataTraffic(int dataTraffic) {
        this.dataTraffic = dataTraffic;
    }

    public int getContractDuration() {
        return contractDuration;
    }

    public void setContractDuration(int contractDuration) {
        this.contractDuration = contractDuration;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

class IntenetPackageModel:

```
package sample;

import com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.IiopUrl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InternetPackageModel {
    private List<InternetPackage> salesHistory;
    private String userName;

    public InternetPackageModel() {
        this.salesHistory = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addSale(InternetPackage internetPackage) {
        salesHistory.add(internetPackage);
    }

    public void deleteSale(String userName) {
        if (salesHistory != null) {
            salesHistory.removeIf(packageItem -> packageItem.getUserName().equals(userName));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Eroare: Lista salesHistory nu este inițializată.");
        }
    }

    public List<InternetPackage> getSalesHistory() {
        return new ArrayList<>(salesHistory);
    }

    public String getAllSalesHistory() {
        StringBuilder history = new StringBuilder();
        for (InternetPackage internetPackage : salesHistory) {
            history.append("Vânzare ID: ").append(internetPackage.getUniqueId()).append("\n")
                    .append("Nume Client: ").append(internetPackage.getFirstName()).append(" ").append(internetPackage.getLastName()).append("\n")
                    .append("Viteză: ").append(internetPackage.getSpeed()).append(" Mbit/s").append("\n")
                    .append("Trafic de date: ").append(internetPackage.getDataTraffic()).append(" GB").append("\n")
                    .append("Durată contract: ").append(internetPackage.getContractDuration()).append(" ani").append("\n")
                    .append("Adresă: ").append(internetPackage.getAddress()).append("\n")
                    .append("------------------------------\n");
        }
        return history.toString();
    }

}
```

class Main:

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Formular Înregistrare Vânzare Pachet Internet");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>

<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import java.lang.Integer?>
<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="2000" vgap="2000" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <VBox spacing="10" alignment="center">
        <Label text="Înregistrare Vânzare Pachet Internet" styleClass="header-label"/>

        <HBox spacing="10">
            <Label text="Viteză:"/>
            <ChoiceBox fx:id="speedChoiceBox">
                <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                        <Integer fx:value="2"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="5"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="10"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="20"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="50"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="100"/>
                    </FXCollections>
                </items>
            </ChoiceBox>
        </HBox>

        <HBox spacing="10">
            <Label text="Trafic de date:"/>
            <ChoiceBox fx:id="dataTrafficChoiceBox">
                <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                        <Integer fx:value="1"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="5"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="10"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="100"/>
                        <String fx:value="Flat"/>
                    </FXCollections>
                </items>
            </ChoiceBox>
        </HBox>

        <HBox spacing="10">
            <Label text="Durată contract:"/>
            <ChoiceBox fx:id="contractDurationChoiceBox">
                <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                        <Integer fx:value="1"/>
                        <Integer fx:value="2"/>
                    </FXCollections>
                </items>
            </ChoiceBox>
        </HBox>
        <TextField fx:id="firstNameField" promptText="Prenume"/>
        <TextField fx:id="lastNameField" promptText="Nume"/>
        <TextArea fx:id="addressArea" promptText="Adresă"/>
        <TextField fx:id="userNameField" promptText="Nume Utilizator"/>

        <Button text="Înregistrare Vânzare" onAction="#registerSale"/>
        <Button text="Ștergere Vânzare" onAction="#deleteSale"/>

        <Label text="Istoric Vânzări" styleClass="header-label"/>
        <TextArea fx:id="salesHistoryArea" editable="false"/>

    </VBox>
</GridPane>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>internet-sales-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

thse are the errors

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.InternetPackageModel.lambda$deleteSale$0(InternetPackageModel.java:22)
at java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1415)
at sample.InternetPackageModel.deleteSale(InternetPackageModel.java:22)
at sample.Controller.deleteSale(Controller.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:276)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

A apărut o eroare la ștergerea vânzării: null

when I put firstName on the field for deleting, they give me errors

Comment: That stack trace is telling you the NPE is thrown inside the lambda you pass to `removeIf` on line `22` of your `InternetPackageModel` class. Either `packageItem.getUserName()` is returning null or the list contains null elements. My guess is the former because, as far as I can tell, you never assign anything to the `InternetPackage.userName` field. See [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/6395627) for more information.